# ( __ printf __ ) cannot be found in DLL (programfiles(x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\as.exe)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, wxwidgets, mingw32

I'm trying to learn wxwidgets for cross platform GUI development, however I faced a problem.

When try to build wxwidgets with mingW32 I run into errors. I installed minGW32 with codeblocks 16.1 (works fine), added PATH to System Environment. Downloaded all possibilities from wxwidgets.org. None of them wants to compile when I try to compile wxwidgets library from cmd with mingw32. I go into `wxwidgets/build/msw`, typed several versions but to mention one:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITIC=1 UNICODE=1
```

(tried without shared, monolitic, even debug mode)

**About the error:**

```
( __ printf __ ) cannot be found in DLL
(programfiles(x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\as.exe)
```

I have the exe, tried to reinstall everything from scratch several times. I'm using Windows 10.

```
gcc -c -o gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I..\..\include -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -D__WXMSW__  -D_UNICODE   -MTgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o -MFgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/regex/regcomp.c
makefile.gcc:5778: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1
```

**Update:**

After reinstalling and deleting everything connected to this, the problem has changed. The code I use, tried without the flag, and with flag but only"-std=gnu++11" too:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release CXXFLAGS="-fno-keep-inline-dllexport -std=gnu++11"
```

The new error code:

```
gcc -c -o gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I..\..\include -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -D__WXMSW__  -D_UNICODE   -MTgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o -MFgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/regex/regcomp.c
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
makefile.gcc:5702: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1
```

Any infos about the fact that I could not ever compile wxwidget with codeblocks' built in compiler? without addons?

Comment: what version of MinGW do you have? Where did you get it from?

Comment: I cannot find it anywhere, looks like a mix of compilers. I am a little bit confused. I downloaded the compiler with codeblocks 16.01 from codeblocks.org(codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe), it writes about tdm-gcc 4.9.2 I do not know If it is part of mingw or it is mingw or it is complete different. I am not familiar with compilers yet.

Comment: Is it possible that you might have different versions of MinGW on your system and they are clashing with each other.

Comment: I was thinking about the same, however there are many youtube videos downloading 16.01 C::B and then just installing wxwidgets, compiling successfully so I do not think so..

Comment: @Zahovay, open up a command propmpt and type `gcc --version`. What does it give you? Also at the command prompt - type `set` and see if $PATH variable contains multiple instances of gcc/mingw.

Comment: @Igor gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2 is the version and only one (codeblocks') mingw is included, even visual studio is not included here, not sure if it would make sense...  Any other ideas that might solve it?

Comment: "MONOLITIC=1" uses many memory. Perhaps your server has some kind of limit or cuota in the amount of available RAM. Try without this flag.

Comment: @Ripi2 As I mentioned in the description I tried them already, and I try to build it on my laptop with 8GB of RAM. The error has changed, going to update the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete everything: wxWidgets, Code::Blocks and MinGW or TDM-GCC

* Download and install C::B, **without** MinGW or TDM

* Download TDM-GCC from [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download). If you install both 32 & 64 bits versions I suggest you to install them in two different folders.

* Download wxWidgets

Open a command window. Say you have TDM at "C:\TDM32" and wxWidgets at "C:\myWX".

Use these commands to compile wxWidgets:

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\TDM32\bin
cd C:\myWX\build\msw
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITIC=1 UNICODE=1
```

This should build an only `.dll` file with most of wxWidgets. Not OpenGL.

If you prefer several `.dll` don't use "Monolitic=1"

If you prefer not using wx'dlls, but static '.a' files added to your app, don't use "shared=1"

If you want to step into wxWidgets code when using a debugger, use "BUILD=debug"

If you want OpenGL use "USE_OPENGL=1"

To build wxWidgets with C++11 use `CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11"`

For your own app you must tell C::B:

* where the TDM compiler can be found

* where the wxWidgets headers can be found

* where the wxWidgets libraries (.dll or .a depending if you compiled with "shared") can be found

Comment: I will probably mark your answer as accepted, because it is, however my problem is that I have to use c::b at University so I would not like to change the compilers due to having "hand in" projects that will be compiled by a server(with MingW32). The problem still exist and it is something about my computer. A friend of mine was able to compile the library with c::b with MingW32.

Comment: If you want to use the already-used-by-CB compiler, you can find which is at CB->settings->compiler 'toolchain executables`. But consider setting another compiler only for your app: After adding a new compiler (by copy & rename an existing one and re-setting its toolchain executables) select it at 'Project build options'. Of course, try also not to mix different wxWidgets builds; this is easy if you add "CFG=mycfg" flags to the cmd line used to compile wx.

Comment: I would possibly mix up the two.. I am kind of new to GUI development and even a simple UI with take all my energy. Do not want to deal with switching compilers between University and home.. But Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.